# How to append timestamp to mysql time returned by curdate()?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

In Mysql, we have a function `

> curdate()

` which returns today's date.

i.e when execute

`select curdate();`

it returns date as,

> 2018-06-22

I want to append the time stamp to this date like

```
hh:mm:ss
```

How can I do it? Please help me.

I want to query database with attached timestamp.

something like this,

```
select * from user where user_created_on >= (curdate() 00:00:00)
```

timestamp is

```
00:00:00.
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading this article https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_timestamp.asp

Comment: @Travis, thanks good information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate time section:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_created_on >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Even the TIMESTAMP function does the same. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user where user_created_on >= getdate()
```

or

```
select * from user where user_created_on >= now()
```

both of these will have that timestamp with hours,mins, and seconds

ps: there is a `curtime()` that gets the timestamp as well as `convert(varchar, curdate(), 108)` will too :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want all hours of the day you can use

```
where data_inicio between (CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00')) and (CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59'));
```